# AVAssetWriter finishWriting failing and producing videos that can only be watched for 50%

Tags: objective-c, ios, avfoundation

I am currently capturing video and audio using AVCaptureSession and have set up the pipeline to write out the data to disk using an AVAssetWriter. For short videos this is working fine absolutely no issues.

However if the length of the recorded media goes over some arbitrary time, usually around 2 minutes then the call to finish writing fails but still manages to produce a video file that only plays back around 50% of its content. I continuously call isReadyForMoreMediaData and appendSampleBuffer during writing and they always returns true. I seem to get no notification that something has gone wrong until the finishWriting call.

The AVAssetWriters Error is set to the following after the failed finishWriting call

```
Capture failed to end with status 3 and error Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11800 "The operation could not be completed" UserInfo=0x210b7880 {NSLocalizedFailureReason=An unknown error occurred (268451843), NSUnderlyingError=0x210b1ee0 "The operation couldn‚Äôt be completed. (OSStatus error 268451843.)", NSLocalizedDescription=The operation could not be completed}
```

Not the most useful error in the world...

This is followed shortly by a call to the AVCaptureSessionRuntimeErrorNotification listener that I have set up which contains the error

```
Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11819 "Cannot Complete Action" UserInfo=0x21011940 {NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Try again later., NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot Complete Action}
```

Again not very helpful...

This is the code i Use to configure the AVAssetWriter input for audio

```
    //\Configure Audio Writer Input
AudioChannelLayout acl;
bzero(&acl, sizeof(acl));
acl.mChannelLayoutTag = kAudioChannelLayoutTag_Stereo;

NSDictionary*  audioOutputSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                      [ NSNumber numberWithInt: kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC], AVFormatIDKey,
                                      [ NSNumber numberWithInt: 2 ], AVNumberOfChannelsKey,
                                      [ NSNumber numberWithFloat: 44100.0 ], AVSampleRateKey,
                                      [ NSData dataWithBytes: &acl length: sizeof( AudioChannelLayout ) ], AVChannelLayoutKey,
                                      [ NSNumber numberWithInt: 64000 ], AVEncoderBitRateKey,
                                      nil];


m_audioWriterInput = [[AVAssetWriterInput assetWriterInputWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio outputSettings:audioOutputSettings] retain];
```

This is the code I use to configure the AVAssetWriterInput for video

```
        videoSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                     AVVideoCodecH264, AVVideoCodecKey,
                     [NSNumber numberWithInt:640], AVVideoWidthKey,
                     [NSNumber numberWithInt:480], AVVideoHeightKey,
                     nil];


m_videoWriterInput = [[AVAssetWriterInput
                       assetWriterInputWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo
                       outputSettings:videoSettings] retain];

m_videoWriterInput.expectsMediaDataInRealTime = YES;
```

This is the code i use to initialise the AVAssetWriter

```
    m_audioAndVideoWriter = [[AVAssetWriter alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:outputPath] fileType:AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie error:&error];

m_audioAndVideoWriter.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = YES;
[m_audioAndVideoWriter addInput:m_videoWriterInput];
[m_audioAndVideoWriter addInput:m_audioWriterInput];
```

Has anyone experienced similar issues? Or know what stuff goes on inside the finishWriting call that might cause this issue? or maybe someone knows some novel ways of debugging this issue?

Thanks

Comment: setting m_audioAndVideoWriter.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse to NO seem to stop the error occurring. However we need this set to yes as the video ends up on a server where it is streamed.

Answer (score 0):

It is odd that setting `m_audioAndVideoWriter` `shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = NO` will fix this. Actually, if you are grabbing the encoded frames from the file and then streaming them I would make sure you set the `shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse` to `YES`. I got it to work, so I am pretty sure you will be able to get it to work.

Last step of container generation includes writing several important container atoms like `AVCC` that specify `SPS/PPS` for the encoded frames, and other very important metadata.

Couple of ideas:

1. How big of a file are you creating on your test ios device? Make sure you are not running out of space - which would make the last step of `.mov` file creation fail. If the file is getting too big too quickly, I would just tweak the size of the video. Also, I would use one of the presets for the `AVCaptureSession` - just set ( `captureSession.sessionPreset`  to  `AVCaptureSessionPresetLow` or `AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium` ) based on your quality need. Two other settings `AVVideoMaxKeyFrameIntervalKey` and `AVVideoAverageBitRateKey` can help you reduce the filesize as well. I can give you more info, but let's first make sure that file size is an issue :)
2. Have you tried generating `.mp4` file? For your assetWriter, just specify fileType:`kUTTypeMPEG4` option. I would be curious if that makes any difference.